# Running Python script on vb.net

Tags: python, vb.net

I just started learning VB.NET, so please bear with me.

Is there a way to run a Python script on VB.NET?

I currently have a face recognition program using Python. When I run/build that program, a window pops up displaying the live feed of my camera, and the face recognition happens (a box appears when a face is detected, then it starts to identify whose face is that).

What I wish to happen is that when I press a button in the VB.NET program, it will start to run/build my face recognition program on Python (what I must see now is a window form from VB.NET and another window from my face recognition program).

P.S. I can also run the face recognition program on the CMD/Windows PowerShell. So if you guys know how to execute a command on the CMD/Windows PowerShell using VB.NET, it'll also work. Or if you guys have better solution, I badly need it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! I want to give you a heads-up by informing you that here we appreciate questions who has some amount of research effort and attempts behind them (unless of course they are strictly about debugging or about a more specific problem), especially in these cases where the question has been asked and answered a couple of times before. If starting the Python script from CMD is sufficient, have you tried googling how to run a CMD command from VB.NET?

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd command in this way

```
Dim command = "python your_file_name.py"
Shell(command)
```

Comment: `Shell()` is a legacy function dating back to VB6. It only exists for backwards compatibility, which really stopped being relevant more than 10 years ago. Use [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_) instead.

Comment: What do you mean